# Trying to create a cloze exercise with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm a language teacher currently studying educational technology and not a programmer so apologies in advance if I'm out of my depth. I'm trying to create an exercise for my students. The activity is a cloze activity where students will enter one or two words into a space.

The students will see the following - I _______ into the shop.

They have to type in the missing word in this case walk for example.

If the students get the correct answer they get a message and if they get it wrong they will be given a text response that will help them figure out the answer.

I'm trying to create this using javascript and I've come up with the following.

```
// first get answer from inputs

var answer1 = document.getElementById('answer1').value;
var answer2 = ‘Walked’;
var correct = ‘Correct’;
var wrong = ‘Wrong’;

if(answer1 == answer2){
document.getElementById('resultBox').innerHTML = 'Answer 1 = ' + correct + '<br>Answer 2 = ' + answer2;
}
else
{
document.getElementById('resultBox').innerHTML = 'Answer 1 = ' + wrong + '<br>Answer 2 = ' + answer2; 


//
```

Could anyone guide me as to how I could go about doing this. I'm not sure what areas I should look into to do this. This type of activity would be useful to my students and I'd appreciate any help. Many thanks in advance

Comment: You are using the wrong quotes. Use ``'`` instead of ``‘`` and ``’``.

Comment: is this code not working or are you looking for an approach how to handle this type of use-case? Also, your quotes are not the right ones, use ' or " instead.

Comment: Javascript isn't Java despite its similar name. You should remove the java tag and change the subject/title.

Comment: Such things are not easy. You might think: if I just do this here, and wiggle over there, it will do what I want. Maybe so (most likely: not). But very soon you will find that you need to enhance your little project. And before you notice, you spent a lot of time programming. And your project will become more complicated with each change. So: **seriously** consider other options than doing that yourself. You see, a deficient, "sub standard" solution might drive away your students. Are you **really** ready to  get into web development? If not, don't go there!

Comment: @Bram Yes, I'd like to know how I should go about making this. Jägermeister, Thanks for your comment. Yes, I might be out of my depth but this isn't something I'd be introducing to students unless it was working satisfactorily.

Comment: You can do this in many ways. If you want to do this the proper way, I would suggest you to save the data in a database (right answers, sentences, exercises et cetera). Then retrieve the data from the database and show it on the screen. Doing this, I have to note that retrieving data from client-side JavaScript is a very bad practice so you need some kind of backend (PHP, Java, .NET, NodeJS) that retrieves the data from the database and serves it to the client (javascript). I would suggest to take a look at the concepts: rest api, database, backend, client server. Note that this is not easy :)

Comment: Note that code written in JavaScript is accessible by your students, if they look in the source code, because it is instantiated by the browser. If you do want to have your data shielded from nosy students you should go with databases.

Comment: Many thanks @Bram for putting me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables need to use either ' ' or " ".

```
var answer2 = "Walked";
var correct = 'Correct';
var wrong = "Wrong";
```

Also you are not closing the else block.

```
else
{
    document.getElementById('resultBox').innerHTML = 'Answer 1 = ' + wrong +   '<br>Answer 2 = ' + answer2; 
}
```

Lastly, Java and Javascript are two very different things. A quick Google search will give you a lot of information on their differences.

Comment: Thanks for the advice duncan. I appreciate the help.